# How to use Bibus to reference website?

Tags: 13.04, libreoffice

This might seem a very dumb question but I can't find a way to reference a website; I've tried to use the WWW type option but it's not working for me. I haven't found a way to do this in the documentation.
Anyway, what I really want to create is this: (Preferably APA style)

> Satalkar, B. (2010, July 15). Water aerobics. *Buzzle.com*. Retrieved July 16, 2010, from *http://www.buzzle.com*.

Extra Question: Is is possible to do this using only LibreOffice?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign different formats to different reference types.
First you have to fill in the references data, selecting www type.

Afterwards you can select from the main menu Styles - New - Format Fields and Format Editor (or similar, as I dont use the english version). In this sections you might select "WWW" and then activate the details below to define the format. 
In the documentation this part seems to be missing, but it is quite simple. In the format editor above you can define the fields you want to display (Author, Year etc.). You can change them and define which separators (,.; etc.) you want to use. At the bottom side you can see a preview of your format.

Comment: Thank you very much, although I did the formatting by hand. The sad part is that now I'm having problems connecting Bibus and Writer, the OOo_pipe(10)) error :(

Comment: Oh, thats a pitty. When I used Bibus to make my exams, it was still with Open Office and it worked very well. As far as I understand, Bibus "listens" to OOo. So when you first open the program, you have to set up the connection. Under Tools - Connection wizard, you can do this again. Open Office has to be closed completely with "Quit" before.

Comment: Success! (Well I figured it out like 3 min after I posted the comment XD) But thanks anyway. You are a life saver